# Update Multiple Rows in MySQL With Similar Content

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, multiple-records

I have an event table. (I didn't create this table)

The fields are id, event_id, start_date, end_date, e_status

The only thing that is **not unique** is the id. The rest are the same on all rows.

How do I update the status?

I tried:

```
UPDATE events 
    SET e_status = 
        CASE event_id 
            WHEN 12830 THEN 0 
        END 
    WHERE start_date = '2016-06-24 17:30:00'
    AND end_date = '2016-06-24 18:00:00' 
    AND event_id IN (12830)
```

No updates were changed.

Comment: So, you just want to change the status of a specific event between two dates?

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is the same on all rows except for the id column, you shouldn't need any criteria in the WHERE clause. You should be able to just have this:

```
UPDATE events 
SET e_status = 
    CASE event_id 
        WHEN 12830 THEN 0 
    END
```

And actually, you don't even need the case statement. If all data is the same except for `id`, then won't all rows have an `event_id = 12830`? You can just have ==>

```
UPDATE events
set e_status = 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new at this, so I'm still learning the formatting of responses. I did the code formatting incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

before editing

```
ID  Event Status
1   USA     0
2   UK      0
3   Canada  0
```

Your simple query would be

```
update event set status=1
```

After Editing

```
ID  Event Status
1   USA     1
2   UK      1
3   Canada  1
```

and if you wants to target specific record just use where clause

update event set status=1 where id=1